# Discrepancies between g++ output and Visual Studio Output. Float Variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, io, g++, iomanip

I am testing out using the clock_t function's in c++ and I ran across a problem. When I compile I do it on 2 different compilers. Visual studio on my Windows 7 computer (2012), and g++ on a Unix system called "ranger". When I  just compiled my code in an attempt to output the time in seconds (up to a thousandth of a second) it takes to run different sort functions, it seems that the g++ compiler completely ignores my attempt to divide the time stamp by 1000 in order to convert it from milliseconds to a second format. Any advice? Is there a difference between g++ and Visual Studio's compiler in regard's to this?

A short code snippet(Output and what i do for division):

```
//Select Sort

begin = clock(); //Begin time
selectionSort(array, n);
end = clock(); //End time
d_select = ((float)(end/1000.0) - (float)(begin/1000.0)); //Calculates the time in MS, and converts from MS, to a float second.

//Output data
cout << setprecision(3) << fixed; //Set precision to 3 decimal places, with a fixed output (0's are displayed regardless of rounding)
cout << n << "\t" << d_bubble << "\t" << d_insert << "\t" << d_merge << "\t" << d_quick << "\t"
    << d_select << endl;
```

Visual Studio output (Correct):

```
n       Bubble      Insert      Merge       Quick       Select  
100000  12.530      1.320       0.000       0.030       2.900
```

Unix output(Incorrect) :

```
n       Bubble      Insert      Merge       Quick       Select  
100000  51600.000   11700.000   30.000      150.000     18170.000
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, not 1000. On Unix, and POSIX in general, `clock()` gives a value in microseconds, not milliseconds.

Note that that, and `clock_t`, are integers; so if you want fractional seconds, convert to a floating-point format before dividing:

```
d_select = float(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Comment: Doing this, it seems to only give me an integer answer, so any sort function that takes less than a second (which would normally give me something like 546 MS as an example) will now only give me 0.000 as the "result" as if it took no time at all. Is there not a universal "convert from time to seconds" call that I can make?

Comment: @DavidRutledge: So convert to a floating point format for the division, e.g. `float(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Comment: aha! Seems my conversion to float wasnt working the way I intended (I just replaced the 1000's in my code with CLOCKS_PER_SEC). However using it the way you wrote seemed to do the trick. Thank you very much! Seems I've learned yet another difference in Unix and Microsoft compiler's today.